# Winforms remove controls on click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu, telerik

In my application I am generating some controls dynamically. On telerik menu control when I click I want to remove those controls and add new controls. I am using the following code. It is removing the controls but only one control per click. Why this code is not removing all the controls at one time?

```
private void radMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in rpvRecord.Controls)
    {
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you removed the first one, you've changed the very collection you are iterating

Comment: What control is rpvRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are deleting the control out of the collection that you are iterating through, which causes a change in the collection and causes the loop to fail. I would suggest using a different style of loop to accomplish this. For example:

```
private void radMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (rpvRecord.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        ctrl = rpvRecord.Controls[0];
        rpvRecord.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I copied the inner portion of B Wells' reply as I forgot to remove the control from the collection in my original reply.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove all controls at once you can just use [Clear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
private void radMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   rvpRecord.Controls.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to remove the item from the collection, and, you might be altering your collection count as you go through the loop by doing a foreach.  You might want to iterate from rpvRecord.Controls.Count - 1 to 0 with i-- like this:

```
private void radMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = rpvRecord.Controls -1; i >= 0; i --)
    {
        ctrl = rpvRecord.Controls[i];
        rpvRecord.Controls.Remove(cntrl);
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
}
```